# Access dynamic id in shiny R

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, shinydashboard

So this is an extension to my previous question.

[Dynamic repeating conditionalPanel in R shiny dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117104/dynamic-repeating-conditionalpanel-in-r-shiny-dashboard)

Here is the shiny code I am using right now.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  selectInput("inpt", "Input Number", seq(1,50), selectize = FALSE),
  br(),
  uiOutput("selectors")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["selectors"]] <- renderUI({
    n <- input[["inpt"]]
    selectors <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
      selectInput(paste0("id",i), "Select number", seq(1,24), selected = 1)
    })
    do.call(function(...){
      box(..., width = 2, status = "primary")
    }, selectors)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It will generate selection windows depending on 'inpt' number selection.

Now my issue is that I want to access the value of generated selection input.

Example: If I have selected 3, three inputs will be generated with id1, id2, id3.

How to access these ids? If I want to print them, how can I?

```
for (j in 1:inpt){ 
    print(eval(parse(text = paste0("input$", paste0("id",j)))))
}
```

But output for this is:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

I thought my eval and parse method is wrong so I tried with just *inpt*

```
for (j in 1:inpt){ 
    print(eval(parse(text = paste0("input$", paste0("in","pt")))))
}
```

Output was (3 was selected in selection input)

```
3
3
3
```

So my eval, parse method was correct I guess.
So how to access id1, id2, ..., idn in above example?

Comment: I think that [Shiny modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  selectInput("inpt", "Input Number", seq(1,50), selectize = FALSE),
  br(),
  uiOutput("selectors"),
  uiOutput("printMyDynamicInputs"),
  uiOutput("printMyFirstDynamicInput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["selectors"]] <- renderUI({
    n <- input[["inpt"]]
    selectors <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
      selectInput(paste0("id",i), "Select number", seq(1,24), selected = 1)
    })
    do.call(function(...){
      box(..., width = 2, status = "primary")
    }, selectors)
  })

  myDynamicInputs <- reactive({
    lapply(1:input$inpt, function(i){
      input[[paste0("id",i)]]
    })
  })

  output$printMyDynamicInput <- renderUI({
    paste("You selected:", paste(myDynamicInputs(), collapse = ", "))
  })

  output$printMyFirstDynamicInputs <- renderUI({
    paste("You selected:", input$id1)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Pretty nice way writing answer. Thanks. However, I want to access all ids individually. How can I do that?

Comment: Just like any other input, e.g. `input[["id1"]]` or `input$id1`, just updated the answer.